# Why aren't my floats working

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I am trying to create a footer for a website and need there to be two sets of links on either side. I have it all in a div and the links for the left and right sides are in uls and their own divs that have ids.
This is my HTML:

```
<div class="bb">
        <div class="fl">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="link">Advertising</a></li>                                 
                <li><a href="link">Business</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="fr">
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="link">Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">Terms</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS I have going along with it:

```
.bb {position: fixed;bottom: 0;list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;text-align: right;}
.fl {display: inline-block;float: left;}
.fr {display: inline-block;float: right;}
.fl li {display: inline;}
.fr li {display: inline;}
```

Why is the footer for the right side not floating all the way to the right side of the page?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the problem is your whole footer `bb` does not have a width. Just adding `width:100%` to `bb` will solve this.

The `fr` actually floats, however, inside the footer `bb`.

I put a jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/Lw93vtgr/ showing this.

Further, you may not want to assign `float` with `inline-block`, the result `display` would be `block` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So i think you forgot set the width of class **.bb**

In your code, `<div class=".bb">` have a width equal to your content.

You can try to set **.bb** class with width 100% or equal to your page width

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the **position: fixed;** from the **bb** class, or else specify the width of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width: 100%` to the class `.bb`.

Comment: Please explain why this would help the OP.

Comment: Okay, so your **fl** and **fr** divs are inside the **bb** div right? When you set up the fl and fr divs and enter those list items inside them, they will automatically set a width depending on the length of the text, so when you view the layout in a browser, it looks like the footer div(the one on the right) is not floating to the right because of the width of the **bb** div. But if you set the width to 100% which will render the whole width of the browser, it will float to the right and or left respectively.

Comment: Please add that explanation to your post by clicking the edit button.